# How do I add spells to my .gexf file using rgexf?

Tags: r, gephi

I am trying to create a dynamic graph in gephi displaying interactions from a discussion forum from an online course.  The nodes are students and the edges point from a student who asked a question to a student who answered.

Many of my edges are removed because they are "parallel edges", which means that they connect the same two people but have different time intervals. From what I have read, it seems it is possible to display these parallel edges if they are coded as "spells".

What code would I use in R to code in spells?

Comment: I assign a weight to an edge that appears numerous times.

Comment: Could you help me with the R code to do that? Would that involve creating an accompanying vector with different edgeWeights and inputing that into write.gexf()?  The documentation indicates that it's a vector, and therefore I'm not sure how to represent a "start" and "stop" and "start" and "stop" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As creator of the package I recommend that you should try the function `check.dpl.edges` (rgexf). This function tells you whether an edge is duplicated or not considering if the graph is directed or not. Following the example (an undirected graph):

```
> # An edgelist with duplicated dyads
> relations <- cbind(c(1,1,3,4,2,5,6), c(2,3,1,2,4,1,1))

> # Checking duplicated edges (undirected graph)
> check.dpl.edges(edges=relations, undirected=TRUE, order.edgelist=FALSE)
  source target reps
1      1      2    1
2      1      3    2
3      1      3   -1
4      2      4    2
5      2      4   -1
6      1      5    1
7      1      6    1
```

where the original relations matrix is

```
> relations
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    3    1
[4,]    4    2
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    5    1
[7,]    6    1
```

On the spells, rgexf also allows handling spells with the functions `add.node.spell` and `add.edge.spell` (see de documentation).

On how to pass a weights vector in `write.gexf`, you should use the argument `edgesWeight`.

Please let me know if you have any doubts george dot vega at nodoschile.org

Best!